# Value 207 at userid of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I have an problem with putting `integer` in `JSONObject`. I have a userid of type `integer` in the web service. The server returns me json string:

```
[{"userid":207,
  "name" :"Azan",
  "email":"az@gmail.com",
  "password":"az123456",
  "created_at":"11-Oct-2013",
  "success" : 1
  }]
```

The problem is that I have to parse userid in `JSONObject`, but `JSONObject` takes only Strings, not integers. It gives me error like this:

```
10-10 08:44:21.872: W/System.err(5706): org.json.JSONException: Value 207 at userid of  type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

The code for `JSONParser` is:

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
          jObj  = new JSONArray(json).getJSONObject(0);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Any suggestion how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check @Waldheinz's answer to fix a bug in your code.

Second, you don't have an `int` and not a `JSONObject` on the first position of your `JSONArray`, hence it won't work. To create a new `JSONObject` and add that `int` to it use `new JSONObject().append("userid", new JSONArray(json).getInt(0));`

And last, the thing you're doing with `ThreadPolicy` is not good at all. Make sure you remove it and put your code into a separate thread for production.

Comment: I try the @Waldheinz's answer and I also remove the ThreadPolicy from the code. When I use jObj=new JSONObject().append("userid", new JSONArray(json).getInt(0));
It give me error at append and suggest to Add cast to 'newJSONObject()'
What to do?

Comment: @Jack, It's hard for me to guide you through every detail, my intent was to give you the idea of the solution. I'm not sure if this code is 100% correct cause I didn't compile it. Work with the documentation to solve this issue.

Comment: In the registration class, I have an error
    W/System.err(1781): org.json.JSONException: Value 219 at userid of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

Could be the JSON parser refuses to parse malformed JSON. The line

```
sb.append(line + "n");
```

looks very suspicious to me, I guess it should be

```
sb.append(line + "\n");
```

Comment: Are you sure the error message is really caused by the code you posted? The error message seems to be caused by failure to do a `Object` -> JSON conversion, while the code above does the exact opposite.

Comment: Yes, it will be caused by the code of JSONParser. Actually, in that code the json get string : [{"userid":208,"name":"man","password":"ma123456","email":"ma@gmail.com","created_at":"11-Oct-2013","success":1}]